# django 1.10 password to be used with flask

Tags: python, django, encryption

I have a django project which i want to move to flask.
The problem is to encrypt and decrypt password the same way django does.
Will that be possible, to implement the same encryption and decryption as in django 1.10. That is i want to create and verify password in same manner in flask as it is done with django. Googling gave me passlib but the doc is not clear about the django version(1.10).Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(Passlib developer here)*

Passlib should definitely be able to handle this case, let me know what parts of the docs weren't clear, and I can try to clean them up! (Latest docs are at http://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

This should help get you started (assumes passlib >= 1.7).

The easiest way to handle things is to create a CryptContext instance, configured with all the hash formats that you have in your database.  It will take care of hashing & verification from there.

For Django 1.10, you probably want something like the following:

```
>>> from passlib.context import CryptContext
>>> pwd_context = CryptContext(
        default="django_pbkdf2_sha256",
        schemes=["django_argon2", "django_bcrypt", "django_bcrypt_sha256", 
                 "django_pbkdf2_sha256", "django_pbkdf2_sha1",
                 "django_disabled"])
```

You can adjust the 'default' above to whichever scheme you want new hashes to use -- even insert a non-django hash format like "bcrypt" into the list.  You can also remove any of those which aren't present in your database.

Once the context object exists, just call .hash() to hash the password, w/ automatic salt generation:

```
>>> hash = pwd_context.hash("foo")
>>> hash
'pbkdf2_sha256$29000$uzyeK0HKJIBR$XQtpjc9nfTdteF1fpk1Jk7FCePwB7S2JLuggiE8UBE4='
```

And then the following to verify a hash:

```
>>> pwd_context.verify("foo", hash)
True
>>> pwd_context.verify("bar", hash)
False
```

There's more details in passlib's [CryptContext tutorial](http://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/narr/context-tutorial.html) if you need.

Comment: Now you can import `from passlib.hash import django_pbkdf2_sha256` and then verify the password as shown.

Answer (score 3):

Lets dig a little:

`django/contrib/auth/base_user.py`:

```
class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
...

def set_password(self, raw_password):
    self.password = make_password(raw_password)
    self._password = raw_password

def check_password(self, raw_password):
    """
    Return a boolean of whether the raw_password was correct. Handles
    hashing formats behind the scenes.
    """
    def setter(raw_password):
        self.set_password(raw_password)
        # Password hash upgrades shouldn't be considered password changes.
        self._password = None
        self.save(update_fields=["password"])
    return check_password(raw_password, self.password, setter)
```

Basically we need to check how `make_password` and `check_password` works, lets do this:

```
def make_password(password, salt=None, hasher='default'):
"""
Turn a plain-text password into a hash for database storage

Same as encode() but generates a new random salt.
If password is None then a concatenation of
UNUSABLE_PASSWORD_PREFIX and a random string will be returned
which disallows logins. Additional random string reduces chances
of gaining access to staff or superuser accounts.
See ticket #20079 for more info.
"""
    if password is None:
        return UNUSABLE_PASSWORD_PREFIX + get_random_string(UNUSABLE_PASSWORD_SUFFIX_LENGTH)
    hasher = get_hasher(hasher)

    if not salt:
        salt = hasher.salt()

    return hasher.encode(password, salt)
```

And the check password:

```
def check_password(password, encoded, setter=None, preferred='default'):
"""
Returns a boolean of whether the raw password matches the three
part encoded digest.

If setter is specified, it'll be called when you need to
regenerate the password.
"""
    if password is None or not is_password_usable(encoded):
        return False

    preferred = get_hasher(preferred)
    hasher = identify_hasher(encoded)

    hasher_changed = hasher.algorithm != preferred.algorithm
    must_update = hasher_changed or preferred.must_update(encoded)
    is_correct = hasher.verify(password, encoded)

    # If the hasher didn't change (we don't protect against enumeration if it
    # does) and the password should get updated, try to close the timing gap
    # between the work factor of the current encoded password and the default
    # work factor.
    if not is_correct and not hasher_changed and must_update:
        hasher.harden_runtime(password, encoded)

    if setter and is_correct and must_update:
        setter(password)
return is_correct
```

Aaand this is just too much :) Lets focus on the haser!

The django default hasher is: `django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2PasswordHasher` - if your code use not default one, you can find all of them in `django/conf/global_settings.py` under the `PASSWORD_HASHERS`

Lets check what `.verify` and `.encode` do on the Hasher object.

```
def verify(self, password, encoded):
    algorithm, iterations, salt, hash = encoded.split('$', 3)
    assert algorithm == self.algorithm
    encoded_2 = self.encode(password, salt, int(iterations))
    return constant_time_compare(encoded, encoded_2)
```

And this is basically `raw` password check, the encoded is a string (db stored password in such format: pbkdf2_sha256$$$ (do not remember this exactly).

Anyway what is happening here - the django created new encoded password (from raw password) and check if the results is the same as provided one.

```
def encode(self, password, salt, iterations=None):
    assert password is not None
    assert salt and '$' not in salt
    if not iterations:
        iterations = self.iterations
    hash = pbkdf2(password, salt, iterations, digest=self.digest)
    hash = base64.b64encode(hash).decode('ascii').strip()
    return "%s$%d$%s$%s" % (self.algorithm, iterations, salt, hash)
```

And this is a method which will create a password from a raw password; Basically you need only the implementation of `pbkdf2` which can be found in `django/utils/crypto.py` and as far as I know it uses only the standard hashlib library. As django is open source - you can borrow this code as it is :) (probably ;))

So to sum all the above:

```
import hashlib
import hmac
import struct
import binascii
import base64

def _long_to_bin(x, hex_format_string):
    """
    Convert a long integer into a binary string.
    hex_format_string is like "%020x" for padding 10 characters.
    """
    return binascii.unhexlify((hex_format_string % x).encode('ascii'))


def _bin_to_long(x):
    """
    Convert a binary string into a long integer

    This is a clever optimization for fast xor vector math
    """
    return int(binascii.hexlify(x), 16)


def pbkdf2(password, salt, iterations, dklen=0, digest=None):
    """
    Implements PBKDF2 as defined in RFC 2898, section 5.2

    HMAC+SHA256 is used as the default pseudo random function.

    As of 2014, 100,000 iterations was the recommended default which took
    100ms on a 2.7Ghz Intel i7 with an optimized implementation. This is
    probably the bare minimum for security given 1000 iterations was
    recommended in 2001. This code is very well optimized for CPython and
    is about five times slower than OpenSSL's implementation. Look in
    django.contrib.auth.hashers for the present default, it is lower than
    the recommended 100,000 because of the performance difference between
    this and an optimized implementation.
    """
    assert iterations > 0
    if not digest:
        digest = hashlib.sha256
    password = password
    salt = salt
    hlen = digest().digest_size
    if not dklen:
        dklen = hlen
    if dklen > (2 ** 32 - 1) * hlen:
        raise OverflowError('dklen too big')
    l = -(-dklen // hlen)
    r = dklen - (l - 1) * hlen

    hex_format_string = "%%0%ix" % (hlen * 2)
    inner, outer = digest(), digest()
    if len(password) > inner.block_size:
        password = digest(password).digest()
    password += b'\x00' * (inner.block_size - len(password))
    inner.update(password.translate(hmac.trans_36))
    outer.update(password.translate(hmac.trans_5C))

    def F(i):
        u = salt + struct.pack(b'>I', i)
        result = 0
        for j in range(int(iterations)):
            dig1, dig2 = inner.copy(), outer.copy()
            dig1.update(u)
            dig2.update(dig1.digest())
            u = dig2.digest()
            result ^= _bin_to_long(u)
        return _long_to_bin(result, hex_format_string)

    T = [F(x) for x in range(1, l)]
    return b''.join(T) + F(l)[:r]

def make_password(password, salt, iterations=2, digest=hashlib.sha256):
    hash = pbkdf2(password=password, salt=salt, iterations=iterations, digest=digest)
    hash = base64.b64encode(hash).decode('ascii').strip()
    return "%s$%d$%s$%s" % ('pbkdf2_sha256', iterations, salt, hash)

def check_password(raw_password, encoded):
    algorithm, iterations, salt, hash = encoded.split('$', 3)
    encoded_2 = make_password(raw_password, salt, int(iterations))
    return encoded_2 == encoded

pwd = make_password(password='test', salt='salt', iterations=2, digest=hashlib.sha256)
# pbkdf2_sha256$2$salt$paft68X11fyh4GG9uMnHtk6pY9QFojoiDckOvLG6GoI=

print(check_password('test1', pwd))
# False
print(check_password('test', pwd))
# True
```

Btw, remember that when making a password your salt should be random. Check the `.salt` method on haser by yourself. ;)
Happy coding!